# Wrong canonical URL in Facebook cache?

Tags: facebook, facebook-like, canonical-link

I have a *[like button](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Like_button)* on this page: http://magazin.skiinfo.de/kaestle

This morning, I made a mistake and put in a wrong canonical [URL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Resource_Locator).

```
<link rel="canonical" href="/skiurlaub-12833-de.jhtml"/>
```

I deleted the canonical URL from the page, but the *like button* still takes this wrong canonical URL. When I look in [the debugger](http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug), I get the right information of my page.

Is there a Facebook cache which I can delete or refresh?

Answer (score 5):

Using [Facebook's Debug Tool](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug) clears the cache Facebook has of your page's metadata. Your page should be fine after running it through the debugger.

Comment: i hoped that would work but like i posted, in the debugger it lookes fine. But when i click the like button on the page the facebook bubble shows the information of that other wrong url.

Answer (score -3):

In my case, as difference between canonical URL and  Fetched URL.

If you make both urls debugging with Facebook Open Graph Object Debugger[a link](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/) , it will work.